# Correct argument for useDelimiter to ignore empty space as well as two specific signs

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want the scanner to ignore three things: empty spaces, `"/"` and `"!"`.
What is the correct argument to use in the `useDelimiter` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useDelimiter` takes a *regex* argument [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)):

> `pattern` - A string specifying a delimiting pattern

So just make sure the string is in regex form.

Whitespace in regex is `\s`, escape that to become `\\s`. `/` is still `/` and `!` is still `!`. You then use `|` to act as an "or" operator to say "either one of these".

Here's how to do it:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\\s|/|!");
```

If you want to say that "consecutive whitespaces slashes and exclamation marks also count as delimiter", then you can add a quantifier `+` to the whole thing:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("(\\s|/|!)+");
```

Answer (score 1):

Scanner's delimiter is just a pattern, so you could use the following:

```
sc.useDelimiter("[\\s/!]*");
```

Comment: Why are you using `#`?

Comment: i want to give the scanner something like "Anna Mills/Female/18" and then use System.out.println(scan.next()) to get each word on separate lines. so the scanner should ignore both empty space and " / " sign. i used your suggested code and it doesn't do that...

Comment: For some reason I had in my mind that OP was using `#` as a possible delimiter. Meant to use `/` - edited and fixed.